# Is there any way to ensure that Event execution is complete?

Tags: c#, .net-5

How to properly close console, Without causing the loss of the data received.

the Task Count is increased when the event is received, and the Task Count is decreased when the event is over. When OnStopping, while is executed until the Task count is 0, it ends.

```
public class TaskHandler
    {
        private static int TaskCount = 0;

        private static object obj = new object();

        public static void TaskStart()
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                TaskCount++;
            }
        }

        public static void TaskEnd()
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                TaskCount--;
            }
        }

        public static int GetTaskCount => TaskCount;
    }
```

```
private void OnStopping()
        {
            timer.Elapsed -= timerHandler;
            // Is there any way to ensure that Event execution is complete?
            while (TaskHandler.GetTaskCount != 0)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Task Count:{TaskHandler.GetTaskCount}...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            _logger.LogInformation($"Task Count: 0... Can close...");
            _logger.LogInformation("close...");
        }
```

```
private static void timerStart()
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000; 
        timer.Elapsed += timerHandler;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private static void timerHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TaskHandler.TaskStart();
            Console.WriteLine("Delay Start");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Delay End");

            TaskHandler.TaskEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens/does not happen vs your expectations with the code above?

Comment: Originally Ctrl+C would immediately end the program, now it will wait for all tasks to complete

Comment: This is the solution I came up with, I want to know if there is a better way

Comment: The solution to which problem? What do you mean by console and events? What is the *original* problem you want to solve? If you want to cancel console cancellation, the way is to use a CancellationToken. If you create eg a service worker (or just a BackgroundService) all background services receive a CancellationToken that' signalled when Ctl+C/Ctl+Z are hit.

Comment: If you use DI you can retrieve the IApplicationLifetime interface and use the CancellationToken returned by its [ApplicationStopping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.applicationstopping?view=aspnetcore-5.0) property

Comment: My JOB is collecting pushing data, and I hope that when I receive SIGIN, it will be allowed to close after the logic is executed.